# Redirect from sub-directory to root - New Wordpress 5.2.3 Set up

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I am using **Wordpress 5.2.3** for a **new website** on a **new server** set up.

I have pointed the existing domain at the new server.

The **old website was installed on a sub-directory**. So Google etc. has indexed `mywebsite.com/sub-directory` for the various pages.

What is the best way to go about setting up a **htaccess redirect** so that any visits to `mywebsite.com/sub-directory/` go to `mywebsite.com/`?

To clarify `mywebsite.com/sub-directory/about-us` would redirect to `mywebsite.com/about-us`

Can anyone please provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your root `.htaccess` file (*before* the WordPress front-controller) add the following:

```
# Redirect from /subdirectory/<anything> to `/<anything>`
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Change the 302 (temporary) to 301 (permanent) only once you have confirmed it works OK in order to avoid caching issues.

> **UPDATE:** If I wanted to add a further rewrite `/subdirectory/old-page` to `/new-page` how would the rule change please?

You would add another rule *before* the above "generalised" redirect. The most specific redirect(s) should go first in order to avoid conflicts - the first rule that matches, wins in this scenario.

For example:

```
# Redirect from /subdirectory/old-page to `/new-page`
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/old-page$ /new-page [R=302,L]

# Redirect from /subdirectory/<anything> to `/<anything>`
RewriteRule ^subdirectory/(.*) /$1 [R=302,L]
```

Note that the above redirects `/subdirectory/old-page` exactly (ie. no trailing slash) - as in your example. If there should be a trailing slash then add a slash before the end-of-string anchor (`$`), in other words: `^subdirectory/old-page/$`.

Or, to make the trailing slash optional, so it accepts request URLs with and without a trailing slash, use the `?` quantifier. eg. `^subdirectory/old-page/?$`. Now, it will match both `/subdirectory/old-page` and `/subdirectory/old-page/` and redirect to `/subdirectory/new-page` (no trailing slash).

Comment: You are a genius @MrWhite that has worked perfectly.

Comment: If I wanted to add a further rewrite /subdirectory/old-page to /new-page how would the rule change please?

Comment: You would add an additional _before_ the generalised redirect. I've updated my answer.